# R omega function data vector type error "NULL"

Tags: r, analysis

still quite new to R so I apologise if this is a silly question but I'm attempting to run a reliability analysis using the omega function and im getting this error :

```
    Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x), :
'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

This is the code I'm attempting to use:

```
soc_omg <- psych::omega(soc_fa,
                    nfactors = 5,
                    fm = "minres",
                    key = c(1, rep(1, 24)),
                    poly = TRUE
                    )
```

and I've attempted excluding *na* data by doing:

```
 soc_corr <- report_data |>
  dplyr::select(SOC.1, SOC.2, SOC.3, SOC.4, SOC.5, SOC.6, SOC.7, SOC.8, SOC.9, SOC.10, SOC.11, SOC.12, SOC.13, SOC.14, SOC.15, SOC.16, SOC.17, SOC.18, SOC.19, SOC.20, SOC.21, SOC.22, SOC.23, SOC.24) |>
  dplyr::filter(na.rm=TRUE)
```

(soc_corr was put through a factor analysis and saved under soc_fa)

not sure if there is something I'm missing but help would be appreciated :)

code for factor analysis:

```
soc_fa <- psych::fa(soc_corr,
                          nfactors = 5,
                          fm = "minres",
                          rotate = "oblimin",
                          scores = "tenBerge",
                          max.iter = 50,
                          use = "pairwise",
                          cor = "cor"
                          )
```

Comment: `is.null(soc_fa)`?

Comment: @Ric hey! thank you for your response :) it just comes back with FALSE :(

Comment: what class is `soc_fa`? correlation matrix? df? Without knowing about your data hard to fix it.

Comment: @SALAR hiya, thank you for your comment :) not sure about class but soc_fa contains the factor analysis data done on soc_corr - i have edited my question to include the code i used for the factor analysis

Comment: I looked at `?omega`, It can accept both data frame and correlation matrix. I used the example data `Thurstone` from the package which is a correlation matrix and running `psych::omega(Thurstone)` and it could execute the function with no error. May be you could try to create pairwise correlation matrix from `soc_cor` containing your variables and use it directly for `omega()` as another option?